# Return values on Jade template

Tags: node.js, pug

I have three registers on db, when i do `each project in projects` i can see the content repeat at least three times but when i do `#{project.ProjectName}` the page breaks, here is my code:

```
extends ../includes/layout

block content
  div(class="wrap")
    include ../includes/header
    div(class="ink-grid")
      div(class="column-group vertical-space")
        div(class="all-50")
          a(href="project/create")
            button(class="ink-button green") Crear proyecto
      div(class="column-group vertical-space")
        div(class="all-20")
          each project in projects 
            figure(class="ink-image")
              figcaption(class="over-top dark")  testing //#{project.ProjectName} 
              img(src="images/splash.768x1004.png")

      div(class="push")          
  include ../includes/footer
```

**The controller...**

```
plain : function (req, res, doc) {
      //Datos cocinados con la respuesta...
      if(!req.user){
        res.redirect('/user/login');
      }
      res.render('project/resume', {
        // resume page view parameters
        title : "proyectos",
        user : req.user,
        projects : Project,

      });
      Project.find({});
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

This is what i did, also, i added a "filter" who just show the projects from the user. Here comes:

```
plain : function (req, res) {
      //Datos cocinados con la respuesta...
      if(!req.user){
        res.redirect('/user/login');
      }
      Project.find({ ProjectOwner : req.user._id}, function(err, projects){
        console.log("***content from Project***")
        console.log(projects)
        res.render('project/resume', {
          // resume page view parameters
          title : "proyectos",
          user : req.user,
          projects : projects,
        });
      });
    },
```